# Why does snowflake restrict bulk grant on pipes?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This question is for my knowledge.

I tried this "grant operate on all pipes in database raw_db to role ingestor_role;" which failed saying that bulk grants on type pipe is restricted.

But that works with "future pipes".

Whats the reason behind this restriction?

Answer (score 2):

The [GRANT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#required-parameters) doc's do mention bulk grants are not supported.

> Note that bulk grants on pipes are not allowed.

I assume this is related to the fact pipes are "running" things, and the ambiguity "how do you apply each class of change" to pipes in different states. Not that I have seen support evidence for thus, but I assume there are states a pipe can be in, that some of the GRANTs you apply to them "are not allowed".

Where-as FUTURE pipes "grants" happen as you create the pipes, and you can only create one pipe at a time. So those are independent, and the meaning of each change would make sense in that initial state.

Comment: I bulk granted rights to pipes using a Python script that granted the rights to each individual pipe and role and it worked; never hit an error.   So... I do not believe that the state of the pipe is an issue.  It remains a mystery why bulk grant is refused for pipes.

Comment: Your example, of not having seen an error does not mean one cannot exist. If your pipes are not stale etc, then are you trying in all states.